# How to deal with link text or link image with string from BeautifulSoup in python?

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I've some `tds` which include link text or link image like below. And when I get the `td` text by BeautifulSoup . The text is shown here:

How can I make the strings like `"u'Language pack English"` and `u'SUSE Linux Enterprise Server for x86 5731SLX Customize'`

I've tried re, but it failed.

```
u'Language pack\n      \t            \t      \t\t: English'`

u'SUSE Linux Enterprise Server for x86 5731SLX\n\t \t\t    \t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t        \t\t\t    \t\t\t\t\t\xa0\xa0\nCustomize'
```

Language pack

```
                                    : English

    <td>

            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server for x86 5731SLX


<br></br><img width="16" height="16" border="0" align="middle" src="//www.ibm.com/i/v14/icons/fw_bold.gif" title="Link icon" alt="Link icon"></img><a href="flowAction.wss?_eventId=customize&contextId=createProductContext_153180107005186045039023158181160233057201186025_5731SLX_2&_flowExecutionKey=_cC224C0EA-DCAC-4303-DDFD-32594E21C48B_k4D15950D-5056-DE43-BCBE-C73C228B3270"> … </a></td>



    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace extra whitespace with single spaces using `re.sub('\s+', ' ', inputstring)`.

The regex `\s+` matches one or more (`+`) whitespace characters (`\s`).

Example:

```
>>> inputstring = u'hello    world! this\n\n\t\t   \tis a \ntest'
>>> re.sub('\s+', ' ', inputstring)
u'hello world! this is a test'
```